Go freezes (but successfully completes)
On MacOs (Apple M2, Ventura 13.5) go run ..., go build ... and even go clean -cache -modcache -i -r (ChatGPT advised) all freeze. After start they do their job (I instantly get binary after go build ... and execute it successfully) but freeze at terminal (Cmd+C, Cmd+D don't help and I can see them in processes (ps -ela) with ±15% CPU.
Tried to re-install (both via brew and manually), checked that all folders in env (go env) exist and have respective rights to write ti them (as ChatGPT advised to do). Doesn't help =( It has started just yet - before there were no problems...

What did you change? Have you checked the according bug tracker for similar reports? Have you traced systemcalls and compared them between a working and nonworking system?

Yep, found several tickets but usual advises didn't help. What I did: 1. explicitly set GOPATH and GOROOT; 2. re-checked envs (that cpu reflects my one arm64); 3. checked access to all folders listed in envs (even set them to 777); 4. made the dump of sys calls (but there I failed as I can't read it...)

here is a dump: https://file.io/LSsUZ92p8IwN

What ChatGPT says analysing the dump: 1. go build freezes at pthread_cond_wait system call that is used to synchronize threads. It is similar to race condition. Details: during main goroutine 1 it stops at cmd/go/internal/cache.(*DiskCache).trimSubdir that may be a problem with compiler cache. 2. pthread_cond_wait usually shows that thread is waiting for signal to wake up

btw, I tried already to clean cache (go clean -cache -modcache) but it freezes as well
